# How can I make application title static after user update it though user page?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I am setting title on a template of the app component. The title has been updating by user input on the user page. How can available that title all over the app?

I have tried through local storage which works but does there any other way to make it available throughout the app?

Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfptvs

[Updates]

When I have implemented this same on my another app, I started getting error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: Bob'. Current value: 'null: Rob'.
```

The above error occurs when execute the below code:

```
this._userService.titleObs.subscribe((title) => {
      this.title = title;
})
```

I have fixed through below code but can anyone suggest the better way to fix it?

```
this._userService.titleObs.subscribe(
  title => setTimeout(() => this.title = title, 0)
);
```

Comment: You used a service, which is the best way to do it

Comment: @Maryannah Yes. But when user navigates to the Home page, the title has an undefined value.

Comment: Not in your blitz, it reloads the page. But I was merely answering your original question, if you have an issue with your code, please explain it in details !

Comment: In your Stackblitz , the page is reloaded because you are using <a> tag for navigation and not router links.

Comment: @riorudo After used routerLink, It works. If you would like to post your answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the service for this is a good approach. For navigation, you should use router links instead of navigating via the `<a>` tag. This avoids a reload of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As Maryannah said you used a service which is a good way to solve the problem. The reason it doesn't work for you might be because your service is under the temp folder. If you put a service in the root folder, all components will be able to access the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed though adding `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
     private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
){}

this._userService.titleObs.subscribe((title) => {
      this.title = title;
      this.ref.detectChanges()
})
```